# Verilog ip core floating point calculations

Tags: floating-point, verilog

sorry for my dummy questions but im new to fpga so i have to ask. I need to convolve two matrices which have floating points. Multiply and sum are my needed calculations. I tried but got some errors. I wanna give matrix element as parameter.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

parameter x12 = -0.253; //one of the kernel element

module float(
    input clk,
    input wire [63:0] a,
    input wire [63:0] b,
    input valid,
    output [63:0] out
    );

    assign a = x12;

floating_point_0 dut(
    .aclk(clk),
    .s_axis_a_tvalid(valid),
    .s_axis_a_tready(valid),
    .s_axis_a_tdata(a),
    .s_axis_b_tvalid(valid),
    .s_axis_b_tready(valid),
    .s_axis_b_tdata(b),
    .m_axis_result_tvalid(valid),
    .m_axis_result_tready(valid),
    .m_axis_result_tdata(out)
);

endmodule
```

And my testbench

```
module tb_float();

reg clk;
reg [63:0] a;
reg [63:0] b;
reg valid;
wire [63:0] out;

float dut1(clk,a,b,valid,out);

initial
begin

    clk <= 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;

end

initial 
begin 

    valid <= 1;
    #10;
    b <= 14;

end
endmodule
```

Can someone show me how to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- It would help if you tell us what error(s) you have.
- I don't see a matrix (as in: two dimensional array) anywhere.

A fist glance at your code shows:

You are assigning a floating point (or real in Verilog) value to a bit vector: `assign a = x12;` where x12 is define as -0.253.  You can't do that. Verilog does not have automatic type conversion for reals.

You are assigning a value to `a` halfway in a module where `a` is an input.
The correct way is to assign `a` to the input vector.

Looking at the code: you are using s_axis_.... ports. Those are streaming axi ports. You are not providing a streaming axi data stream.

As far as I know the `s_axis_a_tready` ports are outputs but you are driving a valid into it.

You must read up on the streaming axi protocol.

Comment: This is just a demo. I just tried to multiply 2 different floating point here then i will send data stream

Comment: ( real x12 = -0.253;
  assign a = x12;)  doesnt work either.

Comment: No because that is still a real to bit-vector conversion which is not supported. Also because their are numerous floating point representations. IEEE-754 is just one standard.